I am having trouble a bug that prevents my player from moving
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Beta game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

playerimg = pygame.image.load('player.png')

playerx = 50
playery = 400

def player(x, y):
screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))

while True:
screen.fill((146, 244, 255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            sys.exit()
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx -= 5
        
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerx += 5
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                playerx = 0
            
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                playerx = 0
    
    
    player(playerx, playery)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

On Vidstudio code when i try to move the player it moves but returns to its original postion immediately after.
